# Randomized quicksort in c yields improper/partially sorted output

Tags: c, quicksort

I am trying to implement quicksort using random pivot

```
void QuickSort(int *arr,int left,int right){

if(right-left+1 > 2){

    int i = 0,storeIndex = left;
    int pivot = left + (int)(rand() % (right-left+1));

    swap(&arr[pivot],&arr[right]);

    for(i = left; i < right; i++){

        if(arr[i] < arr[right]){
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[storeIndex]);
            storeIndex++;
        }
    }

    swap(&arr[storeIndex],&arr[right]);
    QuickSort(arr,left,storeIndex-1);
    QuickSort(arr,storeIndex+1,right);
  }
}
```

but this is giving output that is improperly sorted like

**unsorted:** [81,87,47,59,81,18,25,40,56,0]

**sorted:** [0,18,25,40,56,47,59,81,87,81]

is something wrong with my algorithm because something similar in python worked fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition is obviously wrong: if you pass a 2 element array it won't be sorted, because:

```
left = 0
right = 1
right - left + 1 = 2 not greater than 2
```

Comment: right-left+1 > 1 works i was kind of mixing python version where we check if len(arr) < 2 thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your for loop should be a while loop.